# Copy formatted Email body into new Word document via VBA and keep the text formatting

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I need to copy the email body into a new Word document and keep the text formatted. As far as I've managed I can copy the text from an email body into an **open** Word application. But I lose the formatting.
When I copy the HTMLBody I see the HTML-tags...

Secondary question in this is: How can I start the Word application from Outlook and see it on my screen.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

This is the formatted email in Outlook

[image: screenshot of the email]

And this is the result I expect it to have in Word.
[image: Screen shot of the expected result in Word]

The Code below

```
Sub CopyToWord()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim bStarted As Boolean
Dim olItem As mailItem
If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    bStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
    

'EDIT for Seqondary question:
'Make Word application visible for the user
wdApp.Visible = True

For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
    'wdDoc.Range.Text = olItem.HTMLBody
    'wdDoc.Range.Text = olItem.Body
    wdDoc.Range.Text = olItem.Body
    
Next olItem
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `MailItem` has a word document associated with it. You simply have to get hold of this document, copy its range and paste it into your `wdDoc`

Try this

```
Sub CopyToWord()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim bStarted As Boolean
Dim olItem As MailItem
Dim wdItemWordEditor As Object '* A word document
If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    bStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'EDIT for Secondary question:
'Make Word application visible for the user
wdApp.Visible = True

For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
    Set wdItemWordEditor = olItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
    wdItemWordEditor.Range.Copy
    wdDoc.Range.Paste
    'wdDoc.Range.Text = olItem.HTMLBody
    'wdDoc.Range.Text = olItem.Body
    'wdDoc.Range.Text = olItem.Body
    
Next olItem
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```